# Saving Windows registry hive into memory

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am working with the Windows registry and one function that I came across for save an entire hive is `RegSaveKey`. I notice that you have to pass it a path where you want the hive saved to. I was wondering if it is possible to save the hive into memory instead of writing to a file.

Comment: Why do you need to save the registry hive in memory?

Comment: You can not save it to memory, you have to query the registry if you want values from it.

Comment: Pointing out the obvious: you could save the hive to a temp file, load the file into memory, then delete the file.

Comment: @gov The on-disk and in-memory representations of the registry hive are different. The 'obvious' solution won't do.

Comment: @IInspectable Did the author say what type of representation he wanted? More importantly, I didn't suggest *how* to read the file, you could parse it into a custom data structure or object

Comment: I am just trying to find a way to read it directly into memory without anything touching disk.

Comment: @StackOverflow There is no API to save a Registry hive directly to memory. You will just have to manually read the Registry keys/values you are interested in, using `RegQueryValueEx()` or `RegGetValue()`, and maybe `RegEnumKeyEx()` and `RegEnumValue()` if you need something recursive.

Comment: @StackOverflow what are you _actually_ trying to do? This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: There is no direct API to read the registry into memory. Can you explain why you did this?